# Secure Pen/USB drive - Windows

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to built an application using VB.NET so USB drive can be enabled/disabled [without OS Restart] to secure from file being copied without owner's permission !

Can anyone guide me ?

*Before putting - or down vote, write your reason to do so*

Answer (score 0):

If your USB device is a mass storage type , one way is to remove it's drive name so it will not map to any drive letter and there for it is not visible in MyComputer.indeed it dose not needs any restarts.
I'm not sure how you can do that with VB.Net but i haves seen applications doing it.

another way is to force OS to unplug it! Microsoft has a command line utility for that. I have been using it before. I'll try to find it for you . I'll give you these clues for know to get you going.